# Command is not being run after && in npm script

Tags: node.js, gulp

Here's my **npm script** (defined in my package.json of course) that I'm running:

```
  "scripts": {
    "test": "gulp && mocha-casperjs test/features/specs/*-spec.js"
  }
```

for some reason, all my gulp tasks run fine, but my mocha tests never run.  So what I see when gulp is completely done is this:

```
$ npm test

> someApp@0.0.0 test /Users/me/code/projects/we-do-tdd
> gulp && mocha-casperjs test/features/specs/*-spec.js

[17:34:50] Using gulpfile ~/code/projects/someApp/gulpfile.js
[17:34:50] Starting 'default'...
[17:34:50] Starting 'bundleApp'...
[17:34:50] Finished 'bundleApp' after 17 ms
[17:34:50] Starting 'watch'...
[17:34:50] Finished 'watch' after 7.33 ms
[17:34:50] Starting 'startApp'...
[17:34:50] Finished 'startApp' after 6.63 ms
[17:34:50] Finished 'default' after 34 ms
```

**gulpfile**

```
"use strict";

var app = require('./server'),
    gulp = require('gulp'),
    runSequence = require('run-sequence'),
    browserify = require('browserify'),
    source = require('vinyl-source-stream'),
    gutil = require('gulp-util'),
    babelify = require('babelify');

var scriptsCount = 0;

gulp.task('default', function (cb){
    runSequence(['bundleApp','watch'], ['startApp'], cb)
});

gulp.task('watch', function () {
    gulp.watch(['./src/*.js'], ['scripts']);
});

gulp.task('startApp', function (cb) {
    app.listen(3000, cb).on('error', function(err) {
        console.log(err);
    });;
});

gulp.task('bundleApp', function () {
    bundleApp(false);
});

function bundleApp() {
    scriptsCount++;
    var appBundler = browserify({
        entries: './src/components/app.js',
        debug: true
    })

    appBundler
        .transform("babelify", {presets: ["es2015", "react"]})
        .bundle()
        .on('error', gutil.log)
        .pipe(source('bundle.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/app/js'));
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The command after the && gets executed AFTER the first command has finsihed, because your default gulp task does not terminate, the second command never gets called.

Use:

```
 "test": "gulp & mocha-casperjs test/features/specs/*-spec.js"
```

with **one** & to run the commands at the same time.

Comment: but I don't want to run my tests until after bundling happens, I suppose I should move this stuff to a gulp task then for my tests, or at least it's time to

Comment: write yourself a script, that builds the application and run this before exectuting your tests.

Comment: well I'm doing the bundling and stuff in my gulpfile...so I really need a task for my tests in the gulpfile so I can make sure I run the task after whatever task before it

Comment: 'gulp' is what builds the application, the default task...btw

Comment: thats fine, your build script would be `gulp bundleApp` and your test script would be `mocha-casperjs test/features/specs/*-spec.js`

Comment: well I'm just doing it all in gulp with tasks in a certain order, I do more than just bundle but yea I think we are agreeing

Comment: I mean eventually yes I'll have a 'build' script prob that kicks off my gulp 'build' task and maybe a second for testing...I don't know yet but my tests will run on watch and changes anyway so I don't need an npm script for kicking off tests from npm, the watcher that one my gulp tasks sets to watch my .js files will kick off my mocha tests to re-run

Comment: & doesn't work on windows with cmd, instead one should use npm-run-all https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-run-all